# reactjs update all items in state array

Tags: reactjs

Is there a better way to update all items in the array?

```
deselectAllTags = () => {
    const tags = this.state.tags;
    this.state.tags.map((tag, i) => {
      tags[i].isSelected = false;
      return null;
    });
    this.setState({tags});
};
```

the state array looks like this:

```
tags: [
      {
        isActive: true,
        isSelected: true,
        name: 'cake',
      },
      {
        isActive: true,
        isSelected: true,
        name: 'chocolate',
      },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` returns you another array, so you can simply to this:

```
deselectAllTags = () => {
    const tags = this.state.tags.map((tag, i) => {
      return { ...tag, isSelected: false };
    });
    this.setState({tags});
};
```

Or if you don't have object spread:

```
deselectAllTags = () => {
    const tags = this.state.tags.map((tag, i) => {
      tag.isSelected = false;
      return tag;
    });
    this.setState({tags});
};
```